# is there any way to get a cgpoint from a tapped location without having to used a touch method such as touches began or touches moved?

Tags: ios, objective-c

is there any way to get a cgpoint from a tapped location without having to used a touch method such as touches began or touches moved? I ask because I have a view with a UITableView inside and the touch methods do not seem to be working inside of the table view for some reason.

Comment: [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276988/how-to-get-touch-coordinates-upon-selecting-a-custom-uitableviewcell)

Comment: you could use UITapGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **UITapGestureRecognizer**

You should put that inside an initializing method:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
[theTargetView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];//theTargetView could also be self.view
```

elsewhere inside the target class:

```
- (void)tapRecognized:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        //your coordinates ;)
    }
}
```